# EPSON XP-8500 PRINTER

Tags: epson

Has anybody installed this printer with Ubuntu 18.04 ?
Looking at the Epson website, it seems that no Linux driver has been developped  for it (only for windows and mac OS). Can we use another driver e.g XP-950 instead ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never owned an Epson printer, but I replied to a similar query yesterday [on the Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=296947)

Briefly, it looks as if there is some kind of bug on the Epson website's search facility. It gives no results for Linux if you search for XP-8500 but if you search instead for XP-850 (which is a different printer) it gives 7 results of which 3 actually relate to the XP-8500 - a printer driver, a printer utility and a scanner driver.

Comment: Good news ! I spent a couple of hours on the telephone with Epson aftersale service and they seem to ignore it!